# Javascript to flash via ExternalInterface

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I'm wondering if someone could look over my code. I'm trying to pass a dummy variable from javascript to actionscript 3 with the following code:

HTML:
    `<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"

         id="music_player" width="500" height="375"

         codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">

         <param name="movie" value="music_player.swf" />

         <param name="quality" value="high" />

         <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />

         <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />

         <embed src="music_player.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"

             width="500" height="375" name="music_player" align="middle"

             play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="always"

             type="application/x-shockwave-flash"

             pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">

         </embed>

     </object>`

Javascript:
    var nextTrackLocation = "dummyString";
    getFlashMovie("music_player").jsAlert(nextTrackLocation);

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
  var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
  return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];  }
```

and the actionscript:
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("getNextTrack", jsAlert);

```
function jsAlert(mess){
ExternalInterface.call("alert", mess);
}
```

Does anyone see a mistake?

Comment: sorry, the first two lines of the javascript are within the function 'getNextTrack'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very confusing. I think you are making two mistakes here.

From Javascript you're trying to call a function in Actionscript called "jsAlert" but the function is in Actionscript exposed as "getNextTrack". I think it should be:

```
getFlashMovie("music_player").getNextTrack(nextTrackLocation);
```

Second, where you define the function in Actionscript you overlooked that the ExternalInterface.addCallback actually takes three parameters.

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("getNextTrack", null, jsAlert);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! 

using 3 arguments with ExternalInterface.addCallback gives the following error:

1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 2.

Comment: using 'ExternalInterface.addCallback("jsAlert", jsAlert);' fixed the problem. Thanks so much!!! the documentation says the second of the three arguments gives a point of reference. Could you elaborate on that at all?

Comment: Dan. Sorry about the parameter comment, you are right. I had AS2 in my head which needs three instead of two parameters. Glad it works now!