# Playing a stopped video in flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm having great problems getting Javascript to resume a flash file.
The flash file loads up and the video is set to autoplay `false`. For some reason, any Javascript is not recognising the AS3 function. It keeps saying the function is undefined. e.g.

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
  var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
  return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}

function callToActionscript(str) 
{
     getFlashMovie("video").sendToActionscript(str);
}
```

`sendToActionscript` is `undefined`.

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: are the video and javascript from the same domain? did you allow script access inside your swf? are you sure that you have this function inside swf?

Comment: Hi Igor. Its all in the same domain

Comment: and as for the others my questions? i think you forget to add callback into the swf.. look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918588/javascript-to-flash-via-externalinterface

Answer (score 1):

To use javascript to play your video, you need to do three things.

First set up an actionscript method in your flash file ,eg:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

// create the callback to allow the js to call the method
ExternalInterface.addCallback("playMyVideo", playMyVideo);

function playMyVideo():void
{
 video.play();//where video is the name of the video component
}
```

Next create your javascript function to call the AS method:

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
  var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
  return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}

//js function to call the AS3 method 
function callToActionscript() 
{
 //NB this is the name of the swf in the HTML and not the video component
 getFlashMovie("mySWF").playMyVideo(); 
}
```

Finally you need to allow the swf to communicate with Javascript in the HTML page. The allowScriptAccess param must be set. By default this is set to ‘sameDomain’ which allows scripts only when the SWF resides in the same sub-domain as the host web page. Setting this to ‘always’ allows all scripts to call out from the SWF.

Comment: Hi Martin. Still the same error, I'm afraid. I've copied the AS3 code exactly. Could you have a look at the HTML for me at http://www.thehub.ignitiondrivingschools.co.uk/hazard-perception

Comment: Do you need a href in order to  trigger the js: <a href="#" onClick="callToActionscript();">Click me!</a>?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the vital ExternalInterface callback in the AS3 code (see edited code above). Then in the html use <a href="javascript:sendToFlash();">Click me!</a>